# SwiftUI: Modal view not closing when an item is selected in a list

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

With SwiftUI, I am opening a modal view like this:

```swift
                            Button(action: {
                                self.showingFlightsView.toggle()
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "airplane.circle")
                            }
                            .sheet(isPresented: $showingFlightsView) {
                                FlightsView(flights: self.$flights, selectedFlight: self.$selectedFlight, flightPhase: $flightPhase)
                                
                            }
```

Then trying to close it in a List selection this way:

```swift
                                    // MARK: Select flight button
                                    Button(action: {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(flight.id, forKey: "selection")
                                        
                                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                                        print("Flight selected: \(flight.id)")
                                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                                            self.flightPhase = 0
                                            self.selectedFlight = flight
                                        }
                                    }) {
```

Problem is, if I do not use the trick with dispatchqueue, the modal view does not close (Except using swipe down). selectedFlight is an optional object Flight. If I replace it with a string, it works all normally.

Any idea why if does not close properly with the object?

Comment: Without a [mre], this is going to be tough to diagnose.

Comment: try Dismissing Modal after DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter{} process.

Comment: @Kudos The idea is mainly to get rid of the dispatchqueue... but without, if I close directly via a close button without selecting it closes, but if I select something it doesn't... Very weird behaviour. And if I replace the flight object with a simple string, it just works all good. Could it be that my problem exists because it takes time to process the complex flight object, while most of the time that's something simple which is sent back?

Comment: Try to put Dismissing Modal code in Dispatch. Then let me know what happened.